# References about "neutronic" algorithms

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, neutrons, nuclear-engineering, algorithms

I am looking forward to apply for an internship in 5 months and I looked up the Jobs offers from last year, and some of them asked for a candidate with knowledge of "algorithms applied to neutronics". Neutronics refer to the flow of neutrons in applied systems.

I checked a bit about the literature and found some examples:

- **Apollo3**, a *deterministic* code for neutronics. I have no further info on that.
- **MonteCarlo TRIPOLI4**. [Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:k1P4bzOhoM4J:www.cea.fr/nucleaire/tripoli-4/Pages/Accueil.aspx&hl=en&gl=de&strip=1&vwsrc=0), it is stated that:

> ​
>   Tripoli-4® is the fourth generation of the continuous-energy radiation transport Monte Carlo code developed by the Service d'Études des Réacteurs et de Mathématiques Appliquées (SERMA) at CEA/Saclay.
>
> Tripoli-4® is devoted to shielding, reactor physics with depletion, criticality safety and nuclear instrumentation for both fission and fusion systems. The code has been under development at CEA since the mid-60s, at the Fontenay-aux-Roses center first, then at the Saclay center. Version 4 has been developed starting from the mid 90s in C++, with a few parts in C and Fortran.

Or [here](https://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/nea-1716), it is stated that:

> TRIPOLI-4 solves the linear Boltzmann equation for neutrons and photons, with the Monte Carlo method, in any 3D geometry. The code uses ENDF format continuous energy cross-sections, from various international evaluations including JEFF-3.1.1, ENDF/B-VII.0, JENDL4 and FENDL2.1. Its official nuclear data library for applications, named CEAV5.1.1, is mainly based on the European evaluation JEFF-3.1.1 and is the only one delivered in this NEA package. TRIPOLI-4 solves fixed source as well as eigenvalue problems. It has advanced variance reduction methods to address deep penetration issues. Thanks to its robust and efficient parallelism capability, calculations are easily performed on multi-core single units, heterogeneous networks of workstations and massively parallel machines. Additional productivity tools, graphical as well as algorithmic, allow the user to efficiently set its input decks. With its large V&V data base, TRIPOLI-4 is used as a reference code for industrial purposes (fission/fusion), as well as a R&D and teaching tool, for radiation protection and shielding, core physics (without depletion in this NEA package), nuclear criticality-safety and nuclear instrumentation.

- [**A General Monte Carlo N-Particle (MCNP) Transport Code**](https://mcnp.lanl.gov/)
- **Anderson acceleration**, I am unsure what it is
- **Jacobian Free Newton Krylov**
- **ABN-J : Approximate Block Newton-Jacobi**
- Everything related to the **standard perturbation theory**
- Everything related to the **deterministic** and **stochastic** algorithms

These are examples of the things that are used in "neutronics". However, I have absolutely no clue how to use them, how to work with it so I am looking for documents that explain how to work with it.

Do you have references about "applied neutronics" algorithms/code/techniques/comp sci knowledge?

Comment: Your question is very broad.   "Neutronic algorithms" cover a lot of material and different tools are used in different industries (LWR's, SMR's, national labs, etc.) and in different countries.   Can you give more information on where you are applying?   Normally I would expect somebody who is familiar with "neutronic algorithms" to have a Nuclear Engineering degree.

Comment: This is an excellent question. I am applying to a private lab working on different technologies of nuclear reactors. I will apply to the CEA at Paris-Saclay in the modeling softwares section. In the preferences of the candidate, it is mandatory that the candidate is at its third year of Engineering or last year of Master (not only Nuclear Engineering) and if possible that the candidate know about neutronic algorithms.

Comment: @pmy However, I do not do Nuclear Engineering, but I have solid knowledge on CFD, and I‘ve looked up a bit the MCNP manual and it doesn‘t look much different. Now you might say that if I don‘t have the qualifications to apply to it, but it turns out that some of the previous interns from 5-6 years ago have had exactly the same curriculum vitae as me, so I believe I can honestly apply.

Comment: The MCNP code is not used very much in France.  Apollo3 and Tripoli are both French codes used at CEA (along with many other codes).

Comment: @pmy Yes, I knew about that, which is why I detailed it more than the others

Answer (score 1):

I used [MCNP](https://mcnp.lanl.gov/) for neutron transport simulations for a while as a graduate student.  There are [manuals available online](https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/mcnp_manual.shtml), and (just to give you an idea of the complexity of the toolset) [paid training courses](https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/classes/classinformation.shtml) which regularly sell out.  I haven't read the current version of the manual (which is 750 pages) but the 2005 version (parts of which are available from the link above) discusses some of the algorithmic decisions made in the code which I remember as very educational.

MCNP is export-controlled nuclear technology, which you probably won't use during your internship, but if your question is "how do we compute where neutrons will go in a system?", then its manuals are good reading.  The export-controlled parts of the documentation, and source code for the software, are not things that you're going to stumble across accidentally.

You might also enjoy browsing the software catalogue at the [Radiation Safety Information Computational Center, RSICC](https://rsicc.ornl.gov/).

Comment: Thank you for your fast and experience-based answer. Do you recommend any part in particular of the MCNP manual?

Comment: I haven't looked in that manual for more than ten years. I'd start with the table of contents.

Comment: What exactly did you use to do for transport simulations through MCNP? I have experience in CFD and a lot of time was invested in meshing and geometry. Is it the case for MCNP? What are the "commands", the "input" given by the human operator?

Comment: Specifying the geometry is a big part of the problem, but you have to be careful about specifying materials in a way that you might not need to in CFD. Reactor people use materials (U,Pu) where neutrons with one energy might turn into more neutrons with very different energies. I was doing experiments on a neutron beamline, so I could specify the neutron source as a region on the wall where neutrons appeared with the energy and angular distributions that we had measured.  I was interested in questions like "do the neutrons get around this shielding" and "how many gammas in this detector".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll let the question open for a bit to see if people have more answers to bring.